# Subclassing a Pandas DataFrame, updates?

Tags: python, pandas

To inherit, or not to inherit?

What is the latest on the subclassing issue for Pandas? (Most of the other threads are 3-4 years old).

I am hoping to do something like ...

```
import pandas as pd

class SomeData(pd.DataFrame):
    # Methods
    pass

ClsInstance = SomeData()

# Create a new column on ClsInstance?
```

Comment: you can do that but then what exactly you want to do after that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how I've done it.  I've followed advice found:

- [**subclassing-pandas-data-structures**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#extending-subclassing-pandas)
- [**Fix Finalize Issue**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13208#issuecomment-326556232)

The example below only shows the use of constructing new subclasses of `pandas.DataFrame`.  If you follow the advice in my first link, you may consider subclassing `pandas.Series` as well to account for taking single dimensional slices of your `pandas.DataFrame` subclass.

## Defining `SomeData`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class SomeData(pd.DataFrame):
    # This class variable tells Pandas the name of the attributes
    # that are to be ported over to derivative DataFrames.  There
    # is a method named `__finalize__` that grabs these attributes
    # and assigns them to newly created `SomeData`
    _metadata = ['my_attr']

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        """This is the key to letting Pandas know how to keep
        derivative `SomeData` the same type as yours.  It should
        be enough to return the name of the Class.  However, in
        some cases, `__finalize__` is not called and `my_attr` is
        not carried over.  We can fix that by constructing a callable
        that makes sure to call `__finlaize__` every time."""
        def _c(*args, **kwargs):
            return SomeData(*args, **kwargs).__finalize__(self)
        return _c

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # grab the keyword argument that is supposed to be my_attr
        self.my_attr = kwargs.pop('my_attr', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def my_method(self, other):
        return self * np.sign(self - other)
```

---

## Demonstration

```
mydata = SomeData(dict(A=[1, 2, 3], B=[4, 5, 6]), my_attr='an attr')

print(mydata, type(mydata), mydata.my_attr, sep='\n' * 2)

   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

<class '__main__.SomeData'>

an attr
```

```
newdata = mydata.mul(2)

print(newdata, type(newdata), newdata.my_attr, sep='\n' * 2)

   A   B
0  2   8
1  4  10
2  6  12

<class '__main__.SomeData'>

an attr
```

```
newerdata = mydata.my_method(newdata)

print(newerdata, type(newerdata), newerdata.my_attr, sep='\n' * 2)

   A  B
0 -1 -4
1 -2 -5
2 -3 -6

<class '__main__.SomeData'>

an attr
```

---

## Gotchas

This borks on the method `pd.DataFrame.equals`

```
newerdata.equals(newdata)  # Should be `False`
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-304-866170ab179e> in <module>()
> ----> 1 newerdata.equals(newdata)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/3.6.ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in equals(self, other)
>    1034         the same location are considered equal.
>    1035         """
> -> 1036         if not isinstance(other, self._constructor):
>    1037             return False
>    1038         return self._data.equals(other._data)
>
> TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
> ```

What happens is that this method expected to find an object of type `type` in the `_constructor` attribute.  Instead, it found my callable that I placed there in order to fix the `__finalize__` issue I came across.

**Work around**

Override the `equals` method with the following in your class definition.

```
    def equals(self, other):
        try:
            pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(self, other)
            return True
        except AssertionError:
            return False

newerdata.equals(newdata)  # Should be `False`

False
```

Comment: what about selecting: `df = df[['column1', 'column1']]`, and similar,  how do you make it return your type instead of pandas.core.DataFrame?