# Python class derived from pandas DataFrame with list/DataFrame attribute

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I am trying to create a class derived from pandas DataFrame. The class shall have each an attribute of type `string`, `DataFrame` and `list`. There is no problem with the `string` attribute, but `DataFrame` and `list` each cause a warning. Despite the warnings, the code seems to behave correctly.

Can anyone help me to fix my code? Or suppress the warnings?

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

class MyClass(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, arg_string, arg_dataframe, *arg_params):
        pd.DataFrame.__init__(self)
        self._string    = arg_string
        self._dataframe = arg_dataframe
        self._params    = arg_params

if __name__=='__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    c1 = MyClass("test", df, 1, 2, 3)

    print(c1._string)
    print(c1._dataframe)
    print(c1._params)
```

**Warning message:**

```
so_example.py:7: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribu
te name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  self._dataframe = arg_dataframe

so_example.py:8: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribu
te name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access
  self._params    = arg_params
```

**Stdout:**

```
test
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to subclass a dataframe.

I've answered how to subclass here -> [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47468205/2336654)

---

Why have an attribute of a dataframe that is another dataframe?  If you want an object that has several attributes, one of which is a dataframe, that's fine.  Just don't define the class as `class MyClass(pd.DataFrame):` but `class MyClass(object):` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think that link will help a lot. I want an obejct, that behaves like a dataframe and has private members, some of which are again dataframes (or subclasses of dataframe). Is this conceptually bad style?

Comment: Probably.  But I think you can accomplish your task if you pass the name of your attributes into the `_metadata` class variable.