# Inheriting an attribute that is a pandas dataframe from Parent class in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oop, inheritance

I have a class where one of the attributes is a pandas dateframe.

```
class AthletesJsonReader(object):
    def __init__(self, df=None, # A lot of other irrelevant attributes )
    self.df = df
```

And a method that's writing it.

```
    def pd_table(self):
        d = {'Name': self.names, 'PTS': self.pts, 'REB': self.reb, 'AST': self.ast, 'STL': 
              self.stl,
             'BLK': self.blk, 'FGM': self.fgm, 'FGA': self.fga, 'FG%': self.fgp, '3PM': 
              self.three_pm,
             '3PA': self.three_attempted, '3P%': self.three_percent, 'FTM': self.ftm,
             'FTA': self.fta, 'FT%': self.percent_ft}
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

when I'm trying to inherit self.df and use it in another subclass method, it's returns none and 
error.

```
    def __init__(self):
        draft.AthletesJsonReader.__init__(self)

    def get_player_stats(self):
        print(self.df)
        player_name = input("enter player's name: ")
        end_name = player_name.title()
        player_stats = self.df.loc[self.df.Name == '{}'.format(end_name)]
        print(player_stats)
```

output:

```
None
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

I've looked up for info about what's happening here and didn't quite found a straightforward answer / or it just me not understanding them.
for example:

[How to subclass pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155951/how-to-subclass-pandas-dataframe)

[Subclassing a Pandas DataFrame, updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466255/subclassing-a-pandas-dataframe-updates)

https://dev.to/pj_trainor/extending-the-pandas-dataframe-133l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are inheriting the class, not the instance. When you create the subclass instance, `self.df` is initialized to `None`. You need to call `self.pd_table()` also in the child class *somewhere* (or in the parent `__init__`, since that's called by the child initializer anyway).

For example, if you have other ways of creating `self.df`, but you want to make sure it's there when you need it, you could do:

```py
    def get_player_stats(self): 
        if not self.df:
            self.pd_table()
        print(self.df)
```

Note: This has nothing to do with "subclassing pandas DataFrame". This would be relevant if you tried to do something like `class MyClass(pd.DataFrame):`